# deploying Websphere 6 on RAD 8

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

I have to deploy WAS 6/6.x on RAD 8. In the dropdown for creatnig a new server I see only WAS7 and WAS 8 as options not 6 . How can I get WAS 6 on RAD 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAD 8 can definitely run WAS 6 and 6.1 server instances; I'm running 6.1 on mine. But you have to select those components for installation.

Using the IBM Installation Manager, you can Modify the RAD 8 installation and select what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You got to change your question to ensure that you are communicating the right information.

You can't deploy WAS on RAD and neither can you deploy RAD on WAS.

You are likely looking to see a WAS 6.x server in the drop down list in RAD,so that you can start/stop and deploy apps built using RAD 8 to these servers.

I don't have a RAD8 with me to help you out. You are stating that the create new server shows you only WAS7 and WAS8.

Have you tried clicking on "Don't see your server listed? Click here link" at the top right of the define New server window.

I don't think it would be listed there but it is worth a try.

I did a quick check on IBM site (see the link below) and it states that WAS 6.1 is part of the Unit Test environment support.

> IBM WebSphere Support - Integrated unit test environments and Feature
>   Pack Support WebSphere Application Server unit test environments: v6.0
>   (remote), v.6.1, v7.0, v8.0

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/application/features/index.html

HTH

Manglu