# Websphere 6.1 server installation in RAD 7.5

Tags: websphere, rad, websphere-6.1

I have installed RAD 7.5 in my system and during the installation I have selected the websphere 7.0 server alone.

Now I want to use Websphere 6.1 server.

How can I install Websphere 6.1 server now?

Do I need to install RAD software again from scratch?

Thanks,
Sasank

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317823/deploying-websphere-6-on-rad-8/8328284

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install `RAD` again.
You can install `WebSphere Application Server 6.1` and add it as environment into `RAD`.